# Why do upgrades to KDM/KDE not preserve changes to configuration files?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, kde, directory-structure, kdm

The `kdebase-workspace` package on Arch Linux only preservers changes made to `/usr/share/config/kdm/kdmrc` when the package is updated. I need to edit `/usr/share/config/kdm/Xsetup` to get my monitors to rotate correctly, but the changes get lost every time `kdebase-workspace` gets updated. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kdm#Session) recommends copying `/usr/share/config/kdm/Xsession` to `/usr/share/config/kdm/Xsession.custom`. I could do this with `/usr/share/config/kdm/Xsetup`, but I thought files in `/usr/share/` are supposed to be managed by the package manager.

It seems like this might be a bug in the package (i.e., should it be saving all the configuration files) or should I be making a change in `/usr/share/config/kdm/kdmrc` to tell it to look some place else and if so where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files under `/usr` are meant to be under the control of the package manager (except for files under `/usr/local`). Configuration files that the system administrator may modify live in `/etc`. This is part of the traditional unix directory structure and codified for Linux in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html). The recommendation in the Arch Wiki to edit files under `/usr` is a bad idea; the fact that your changes are overwritten by an upgrade is expected.

Arch Linux manages files in a somewhat nonstandard way. You can mark the file as not to be changed on upgrade (this is documented on the wiki) by declaring it in `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
NoUpgrade = usr/share/config/kdm/Xsetup
```

You may want to replace `/usr/share/config/kdm/Xsetup` by a symbolic link to a file under `/etc` (e.g. `/etc/kdm/Xsetup`), to make it easier to keep track of the customizations that you've made.